# NSWindowController orderOut crashes in Mac Yosemite 10.10

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

The following code worked perfectly for Mavericks (10.9), but once I upgraded to Yosemite 10.10 it crashes. What is the best way to overcome sheets over-outs?

My class holds a member:

```
EmailClientWindowController* emailClientSheet;
```

(while EmailClientWindowController : NSWindowController)

Upon some button click I present the window as modal sheet:

```
self.emailClientSheet = [[EmailClientWindowController alloc] initWithDocument:document];
[NSApp beginSheet:self.emailClientSheet.window modalForWindow:self.view.window modalDelegate:self
       didEndSelector:@selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
```

And its didEndSheet method is as following:

```
- (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    self.emailClientSheet = nil;
    [sheet orderOut:self];
}
```

But, the line [sheet orderOut:self] is now crashing in Yosemite! And this code has been working for several years now! What is the best way to overcome this issue?

Thanks!

Nili

Comment: Try `[sheet close]` maybe?

Comment: Same crash happens there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to replace the order of the nil assignment and the orderOut. Meaning:

```
- (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    [sheet orderOut:self];
    self.emailClientSheet = nil;
}
```

Still didn't figure out what Apple changed in OSX 10.10 in comparison to 10.9, probably some memory optimizations. Didn't find any related clues in 10.10 release notes nor in blogs. Anyhow this code is better for releasing windows.